# Copy all child pages to another parent

Tags: confluence

Is it possible in confluence to copy all child pages to another parent page?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Copy Page Tree Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.nurago.confluence.plugins.treecopy) available from Atlassian Marketplace. It can copy page hierarchies within the same space as well as to other spaces. I'm the author of that plugin in case you have follow up questions.

Answer (score 1):

With the [copy space plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/212) you can copy pages from one to another space.

You can't copy pages within one space, as the page name has to be unique within a space.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [Confluence CLI](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.swift.confluence.cli)

Answer (score 0):

I created a small [script](https://github.com/grundic/confluence-page-copier) for copying Confluence page with all children, labels and attachments.